# Несколько property="suffix" для ViewResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Допустим я хочу, чтобы `ViewResolver` использовал не только страницы в формате `.jsp`, но и `.html`.

Вопрос: можно настроить несколько `property="suffix"` для `ViewResolver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, для этого лучше использовать несколько различных резолверов.

[Наример](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/configure-multiple-view-resolvers-priority-in-spring-mvc/):

```
<beans>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/spring-views.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
        <property name="basename" value="spring-views"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```